# Replace values in a column based on a dictionary (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, replace

I have a text file (subject_ID_dict.csv) that contains subject # mappings, like this:

```
30704   703
30705   849
30714   682
30720   699
30727   105
30729   708
30739   707
30757   854
30758   710
30763   724
30771   715
30773   99
30777   719
30779   717
30798   728
30805   732
30809   727
30831   734
30838   736
30868   735
30908   742
30929   115
30942   747
30944   743
30993   745
31006   116
31018   113
31040   758
31055   756
31057   755
31058   754
31068   760
31091   885
31147   764
31193   765
31196   767
31202   766
31209   117
31235   118
31268   772
31275   771
40017   -88
40018   542
40021   557
40023   28
```

I want to load this as a dictionary and use it to replace values in the first column in data.csv. So 40023 would become 28, for example.

Here is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

# load text file where we want to replace things
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0)

# make dictionary
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('subject_ID_dict.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        line=str(line)
        k, v = map(int, line.split())
        d[k].append(v)
print df['subid'].replace(d, inplace=True)
```

when I print d, I get this (snippet because it's quite long):

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {30720: [699], 30727: [105], 30729: [708], 30739: [707], 70319: [7066], 30757: [854], 30758: [710], 30763: [724], 30771: [715], 30773: [99], 70514: [7052], 30777: [719], 30779: [717], 70721: [-88], 70405: [-88], 30798: [728], 50331: [503310], 30805: [732], 30809: [727], 70674: [7080], 30831: [734], 30838: [736],
```

How can I remap the "subjid" column of data.csv using my dictionary, d, from subject_ID_dict.csv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to facilitate quick replacement, create a flat dictionary. Don't use a `defaultdict`.

```
d = {}
with open('subject_ID_dict.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = map(int, line.split())
        d[k] = v
```

Next, use [`df.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to transform your `subid` column.

```
df['subid'] = df['subid'].map(d)
```

Comment: 'replace' can be used too'   df['subid'] = df['subid'].replace(d)

Comment: I'm a fan of the mapping, well put!